# Trying to print the even indexed characters from a string

Tags: python

Trying to print the even indexed characters from a string:

```
string = input("Please enter your input")
for i in string:
    if (string.index(i))%2==0:
        print(i)
```

When I apply to the above code It gives me output as:

```
Please enter your inputhello
h
l
l
o
```

Comment: The problem comes from the fact the the ```index``` method returns the first index with the character. As L appears twice, only the L at index 2 is taken into account, then it's written twice.

Comment: Can you what you want your output to be? Are you looking for `hello --> h l o` or `hello --> e l` or `hello --> l o`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you want:

```
for i in string[::2]:
    print(i)
```

`[::2]` slices the string. It starts from the beginning of the string and goes until its end increasing the index by `2` per iteration.

Comment: Why not just `print(*string[::2])`? No need for a loop.

Comment: 0 is not a even or odd number that why it is returning the first letter ```h``` he did not want that. if user inputs ```hello``` the output should be ```2nd``` letter ```4th``` letter and so on.

Comment: 0 is absolutely an even number

Comment: @blackbrandt That's a valid possibility as well. I just wanted to keep it in a `for` loop because it's similar to the code presented by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea.

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to make your code work:

```
string = input("Please enter your input")
for i,c in enumerate(string):
    if i%2==0:
        print(c)
```

If you want the ODD characters:

```
string = input("Please enter your input")
for i,c in enumerate(string):
    if i%2!=0:
        print(c)
```

Comment: He did not want according to indexing. In python Indexing starts from ```0``` he want like we do in real life from ```1```.

Comment: If we just do ```i % 2 != 0``` then it will work just fine like he wants.

Comment: @KunalTanwar: You are making that up. And the [parity of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero) is even.

Comment: I am not making that up I am doing what he initially wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Like @dawg did but with just a minor correction.

```py
string = input("Please enter your input : ")

for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        print(c)
```

If we just do it not equal to `0` because in python indexing or python counts from 0 but in reality we count from 1 so if `remainder` is not equal to `0` it will return odd input which exactly what he wanted.